# Given an arbitrary window, of an arbitrary program, can I access a GUI element?

Tags: gui, window

This window has a loading bar active on the screen.

[image]

I would like to programmatically get the value displayed (40.9%) in a script. I don't mind what language is used to get this.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does this app provide any information when you open it from terminal? I do not find it in the repo. Can you provide more infos on where to download it and how to install it?

Comment: @dadexix86 It's called Crash Plan, you can find it on their website. However, my question is meant to be a generic one - is there a way to do this for *any* app.

Comment: It would probably be useful to know what toolkit they use (Gtk, Qt, ...). The answer (if what you want is possible at all) will probably depend on that. Not sure though, just guessing. Interesting question.

Comment: @ByteCommander it's a proprietary Java program that needs Oracle Java. I am completely ignorant about it :)